# How the heat a large amount of water that is safe to use?

Tags: equilibrium, water, heat

I would like to know how heat up a large amount of water ( assumption : 100 liter ) that people could use to take their bath and also it would not be dangerous even if they accidentally ingested it ? .

My idea is that to design a metal container and have the chemical in it . I'll react the chemical that is inside the container and then I'll put the container into the water , which will eventually heat up the water through thermal equilibrium .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you heat water with additives?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/can-you-heat-water-with-additives)

Comment: Why don't you heat it normally, using cooker, boiler, or stove - 100 liter isn't that much.

Comment: An appliance exists for this. According to the [Lowes website](http://www.lowes.com/projects/repair-and-maintain/water-heater-buying-guide/article), the smallest hot water heater they sell is 30 gallons, which will be about 115 liters. You can buy heaters up to 80 gallons (~300 litres) or probably larger.